# Can I say "it" before what it indicates?

Tags: grammar

> 1) When/if/once the system meets the functional specifications, the agency has
>   to announce **it**.
>
> 2) The agency has to announce **it**, when/if/once the system meets the functional
>   specifications.

Are these two sentences interchangeable?

I'm not sure if I can use "**it**" before what it indicates.
In those sentences, I used **it** as "the system meets the functional specification".

Comment: Sentence (1) does a good job. In (2) it seems like "it" is referring to something that was mentioned or discussed in a previous sentence. You could try something like this: *The agency has to announce/confirm when/if/once the system meets the functional specifications.*

Comment: @AIQ Thanks. Then does when/if/once become the object of confirm/ announce? In this case, can’t I use once here?

Answer (score -1):

In the second sentence you do not need the "it" simply because it is a substitute for whatever follows.

In the first sentence it is needed, in order to reference the first part of the sentence.